# Create a percentage column by slicing every 2 rows by the third row in a csv file based on subnumber

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

I have this dataset

```
SubNo Trails Height Weight Nutrition 
19      1      100    30      Yes      
19      2      400    30      Yes      
19      3      810    10      No  
19      4      100    30      Yes      
19      5      400    50      Yes      
19      6      810    10      No  
7       1      911    20      Yes      
7       2      811.   20      Yes      
7       3      811    14      No 
7       4      911    60      Yes      
7       5      811.   60      Yes      
7       6      811    94      No        
20      1      222    40      Yes      
20      2      222    50      Yes      
20      3      789    30      No   
20      4      222    90      Yes      
20      5      222    50      Yes      
20      6      789    39      No           
:       :       :     :       :          
:       :       :     :       :                    
:       :       :     :       :
```

I want to add an additional column that calculates the percentage change for each 'Subnum' by dividing all the trails of one subject by the third one(where 'NO' Nutrition is given). How can I about this? (I did look into the pandas iloc method).

```
SubNo Trails Height Weight Nutrition %change of weight
19      1      100    30      Yes      30/109
19      2      400    30      Yes      30/109
19      3      810    109      No       109/109
19      4      100    30      Yes      30/10
19      5      400    309      Yes      309/10
19      6      810    10      No       10/10
7       1      911    20      Yes      20/14
7       2      811.   20      Yes      20/14
7       3      811    14      No       14/14
7       4      911    20      Yes      20/84
7       5      811.   20      Yes      20/84
7       6      811    84      No       84/84
20      1      222    40      Yes      40/30
20      2      222    50      Yes      50/30
20      3      789    30      No       30/30
20      4      222    40      Yes      40/80
20      5      222    50      Yes      50/80
20      6      789    80      No       80/80
:       :       :     :       :          :
:       :       :     :       :          :          
:       :       :     :       :          :
```

Comment: does `No` always come last ? if so `df['Weight'] / df.groupby(['SubNo'])['Weight'].transform('last')` should work ?

Comment: @Datanovice yes.No is always for Trial No 3.There are total three trails per subject.

Answer (score 1):

This should work.

```
block_length = 3

df['%'] = df.groupby(['SubNo', (df.index // block_length)], group_keys=False).apply(lambda x: x['Weight'].divide(x['Weight'].loc[x['Nutrition'] == 'No'].iloc[0]))
print(df)

   SubNo Trails  Height  Weight Nutrition          %
0     19      1     100      30       Yes   0.275229
1     19      2     400      30       Yes   0.275229
2     19      3     810     109        No   1.000000
3     19      4     100      30       Yes   3.000000
4     19      5     400     309       Yes  30.900000
5     19      6     810      10        No   1.000000
6      7      1     911      20       Yes   1.428571
7      7      2     811      20       Yes   1.428571
8      7      3     811      14        No   1.000000
9      7      4     911      20       Yes   0.238095
10     7      5     811      20       Yes   0.238095
11     7      6     811      84        No   1.000000
12    20      1     222      40       Yes   1.333333
13    20      2     222      50       Yes   1.666667
14    20      3     789      30        No   1.000000
15    20      4     222      40       Yes   0.500000
16    20      5     222      50       Yes   0.625000
17    20      6     789      80        No   1.000000
```

Comment: @JamieOG  thank you much. Worked great. Learnt something new :)

Comment: Sorry, there is an edit.I checked the values and there is an error.In my real data set there is 100 trials per subject divided into blocks of 5.SHere for example,I want to divide the value when the 'Nutrition' is no for that one block(1,2,3) then use the 6th trail value to divide (4,5,6) and so till 100 trials per subject.Could you modify the code?

Comment: OK, I've edited the code. Check it out and tell me if it woks :)